# @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn of JPA InheritanceType does not work correctly in COUNT query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

There is some class like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private int personId;
```

and the its child class is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="employee_id")
public class Employee extends Person {
 [Something else fields]
```

It is necessary to mention that there are some else objects that are extended from Person such as Student that has its own Fk field(such as student_id) to Person entity.

The generated query of the following HQL:

```
select count(e) 
  from  Employee e
```

is:

```
select count(e.id)
  from employee e
 inner join person p
    on e.employee_id = p.id
```

while the correct generated query must be:

```
select count(e.employee_id)
  from employee e
 inner join person p
    on e.employee_id = p.id
```

So the `invalid identifier` exception is raised.

Where is wrong and what I have to do for solving this problem?

**UPDATE**

The table of these Entities are:

person:

```
id                and others files
------------------------------------
```

and the employee table is:

```
employee_id[fk to person table]         others fields
----------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Hibernate allows such kind of inheritance, but it is usually avoid as the result / behavior is less controllable by developer.

Instead, through my previous experience and IMHO, I would suggest to follow below practice which would gives you more control on achieving your expected result by using @JoinColumn since JPA 2.0:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name="person_id")
  private Long personId;

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
public class Employee{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="employee_id")
    private Long employeeId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn (name="person_id")
    private Person person;

}
```

---

UPDATE 1

If using @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn is more preferred, then there is one thing need to rectify in the original code (at least need to assign a name to the PK to give you more control:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="person_id")
    private int personId;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="person_id")
public class Employee extends Person {

    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="employee_id")
    private int employeeId;

}
```

It is because `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` is supposed to let the current secondary table to know which primary key of primary table it needs to reference with.

You can refer to below section of JPA 2.0 specifiction:

> **11.1.40 PrimaryKeyJoinColumn Annotation**
>
> The `PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` annotation specifies a primary key column that is used as a foreign key to join to another table.
>
> The `PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` annotation is used to join the primary table
>   of an entity subclass in the `JOINED` mapping strategy to the primary
>   table of its superclass; it is used within a `SecondaryTable` annotation
>   to join a secondary table to a primary table; and it may be used in a
>   `OneToOne` mapping in which the primary key of the referencing entity is
>   used as a foreign key to the referenced entity[108].

Comment: It is not necessary to have explicit `employeeId` field in `Employee` class as it will be created automatically with this annotation: `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "employee_id", referencedColumnName = "person_id")`

Answer (score 0):

To expand **garykwwong**'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58505521/7598851), you could:

- use explicit `personId` column name (`person_id` and `employee_id` will be used as column names in `person` and `employee` tables):

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="person_id")
    private int personId;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "employee_id", referencedColumnName = "person_id")
public class Employee extends Person {
// Explicit employeeId field is NOT required in the class
}
```

- not use `personId` column name at all and let JPA do the linking for you (`personId` and `employee_id` will be used as column names in `person` and `employee` tables):

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int personId;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
public class Employee extends Person {
// Explicit employeeId field is NOT required in the class
}
```

- not use explicit names at all (`personId` will be used as column name in both `person` and `employee` tables):

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int personId;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
public class Employee extends Person {
}
```

Here is a [demo project](https://github.com/Martin-BG/jpa-inheritance-joined) demonstrating the first option.